# How to include in the report data, with unset or null metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

E.g. request:

```
dimensions: ga:sourceMedium, ga:dimension1;
metrics: ga:transactions;
```

where ga:dimension1 is custom sessionID.

How to include in report sessions with no transactions?

It's can be done by creating second request, but I want to avoid it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with the request like this google analytics will only report on sessions that have a valid value for a `ga:dimension1`. If there are any sessions that have no value set for `ga:dimension1` they will not be included in the reported data. the only way to get this data is making a request without custom dimension.